# AngularJS: Retrieving (or setting a global variable) in ng-data-repeat structure

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In Angular, I'm currently listing some block info using `ng-data-repeat`, and calling the various values. 
This is a snippet of a table which uses the repeat:

```
<tr class="fader" ng-repeat='b in blocks'>
    <td> <a href="/block/{{b.hash}}">{{b.height}}</a>
    </td>
    <td><span class="ellipsis">{{humanSince(b.time)}}</span>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">{{b.txlength}}</td>
    <td class="text-right hidden-xs"><a href="{{b.poolInfo.url}}" title="{{b.poolInfo.poolName}}" target="_blank" data-ng-show="b.poolInfo">{{b.poolInfo.poolName}}</a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">{{b.size}}</td>
</tr>
```

I'm specifically trying to define a function later on in the html, which takes the first (of 6 values listed) for `{{b.time}}` and compare them/average them. However, I don't know how to access any specific value of the b.time iterations.

Ideally, if it were stored in an array I could just define a function which compares `b.time[0]` with `b.time[1]`, and `b.time[1]` with `b.time[2]` etc. Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are going to reference this average function outside of your ng-repeat block, so you should just add a calculation function to your controller code where your "blocks" variable is defined, and calculate whatever you want as usual completely ignoring the fact you have ng-repeat at all.

For example (for an average of first 6 elements)

```
$scope.avg = function() {
     var sum=0;
     for (var i=0;i<6 && i<$scope.blocks.length; i++) {
          sum=sum+blocks[i].time;
     }
     if i=0 return "";
     return sum/i;
}
```

And then later in your HTML code, just use `{{ avg() }}` to output the value

Comment: No matter where I add the avg function, in any controller, when I called it with {{avg()}} I just is not printing anything, which I assume means null.

Comment: can you post an example on JSFiddle or Plunker?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7c26rdt4/ it seems maybe I'm using an incorrect controller... Or maybe the values for {{block.time}} etc is just hidden deep in the code.